# add missing categories in columns in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am having following spark dataFrame. There are 10 distinct values in column country. I want new dataframe as given in the Expected result.

```
DataFrame
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|         Code|       country|                t1|
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|            A|        Canada| 6218.400000000001|
|            A|       Central|              30.4|
|            A|        France|24540.629999999965|
|            A|       Germany|27688.029999999966|
|            A|     Northeast|             51.41|
|            A|     Northwest| 56261.31000000015|
|            A|     Southeast|             55.71|
|            A|     Southwest| 92640.42999999833|
|            A|United Kingdom|              0.64|
|            B|     Australia|145856.31999999806|
|            C|        Canada| 28223.26999999983|
|            C|     Northwest|              0.87|
|            C|     Southwest|              0.44|
+-------------+--------------+------------------+

Distinct values for country column are :
+--------------+
|       country|
+--------------+
|     Australia|
|        Canada|
|       Central|
|        France|
|       Germany|
|     Northeast|
|     Northwest|
|     Southeast|
|     Southwest|
|United Kingdom|
+--------------+

Expected Result :

+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|         Code|       country|                t1|
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|            A|     Australia|              null|
|            A|        Canada| 6218.400000000001|
|            A|       Central|              30.4|
|            A|        France|24540.629999999965|
|            A|       Germany|27688.029999999966|
|            A|     Northeast|             51.41|
|            A|     Northwest| 56261.31000000015|
|            A|     Southeast|             55.71|
|            A|     Southwest| 92640.42999999833|
|            A|United Kingdom|              0.64|
|            B|     Australia|145856.31999999806|
|            B|        Canada|              null|
|            B|       Central|              null|
|            B|        France|              null|
|            B|       Germany|              null|
|            B|     Northeast|              null|
|            B|     Northwest|              null|
|            B|     Southeast|              null|
|            B|     Southwest|              null|
|            B|United Kingdom|              null|
|            C|     Australia|145856.31999999806|
|            C|        Canada| 28223.26999999983|
|            C|       Central|              null|
|            C|        France|              null|
|            C|       Germany|              null|
|            C|     Northeast|              null|
|            C|     Northwest|              0.87|
|            C|     Southeast|              null|
|            C|     Southwest|              0.44|
|            C|United Kingdom|              null|
```

How can i achieve this expected output in scala ? I have referred function/method for the dataset but not able to find any clue that will me to start with this.

> Note that there could be multiple column, so for the multiple column
>   logic goes same that i want to insert missing categories against each
>   category in all columns.

I am beginner to spark scala. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `df.select($"country")).distinct`?

Comment: It will return only distinct values for country column from dataframe.

Comment: What is the input and expected out?

Comment: Please refer the question. I have mentioned both in the questions description.

Answer (score 1):

cross join the distinct codes with countries and then left join that to the original table
something like

```
val codes= data.select($"Code").distinct
val combinations = codes.crossJoin(countries)
val result = combinations.join(data, combinations("code")===data("code") && combinations("country")===data("country"),"leftouter").select(combinations("code"),combinations("coiuntry"),data("t1")).orderBy($"code",$"value")
```

Comment: For example I have taken 2 column only, But there could be multiple columns in this case I think it will not work.

Comment: this does exactly what you ask in the question - if your question is different you should have ask that... In any case crossjoin will give you all the combinations of any columns so if you have multiple such columns you should probably crossjoin them as well before the final left join

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: what I answered is still true - you need to cross join all the distinct values and then left join to the actual data (t1 in your example)

Comment: Yes, But with large amount of data it will impact on performance. Is there any other way ?

Comment: where do you think Spark can magically get the data of which combinations exist?! - not to mention that you actually want all the generated rows in the result. Lastly if you don't have large amounts of data don't use spark to begin with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191841/discussion-between-vvp-and-arnon-rotem-gal-oz).